# How can I tell typescript to include a line verbatim in js without parsing it

Tags: typescript, extendscript

I’m writing an app in typescript to compile to adobe extendscript (an es3-based javascript syntax).

I am trying to use the extendscript-only syntax

```
#include "path_to_file";
```

which is not valid typescript (and not even valid javascript).
I would like to tell typescript to just include it as-is, without parsing it.

I know about `@ts-ignore`, and `@ts-except-error`, but though these prevent typescript from throwing an error, they don’t prevent it from messing the line while transpiling it. In the end the output line is :

```
#include;
```

which kinds of defeats the purpose.

Is it possible to tell typescript not to parse next line and to just include it as-is in javascript code ?

(otherwise I’m going to have to resort to some dark Makefile / cat magic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for by using the alternative extendscript-directive syntax that uses `//@` instead of `#`. The fact it's effectively a comment means typescript will ignore it, but extendscript still sees it.

So change your:

```
#include "path_to_file";
```

to be:

```
//@include "path_to_file";
```

Comment: Thank you ! Though it doesn't really answer the question (how to include a line verbatim), it does solve my problem, so I'll accept your answer. For the record, iirc I had it solved by using this https://github.com/yellcorp/extendscript-commonjs , and telling typescript to transpile imports to commonjs, so I could just use the native typescript `import` syntax

Comment: (and the toplevel include of extendscript-commonjs was done in a pure jsx file)

Answer (score 0):

Solves the problem without answering the question

```
const root = File($.fileName).parent
const file = new File(`${root}/../polyFill/index.jsx`);
$.evalFile(file);
```